# OnePage checkout same Billing and Shipping addresses

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, rwd-theme

I'm trying to combine the billing and shipping addresses into just one option on the one page checkout. Using a modified rwd theme and am looking for some direction on how to implement this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` to local code pool. Find the following method `_getStepCodes`. And remove `'shipping'` from return result

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
```

Copy `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` from `base/default` theme to your current theme for example `rwd/default`. Find the following line:

```
this.steps = ['login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'];
```

and remove `'shipping'` item from array:

```
this.steps = ['login', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'];
```

Also you need update controller `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`. You can override controller in your custom module or edit `OnepageController.php` directly. Find the method `saveBillingAction` and remove or comment following lines:

```
$result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
$result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
```

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping.php` to local code pool. Find the `isShow` and replace with:

```
public function isShow()
{
    return false;
}
```

Copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` from `base/default` theme to your current theme, for example `rwd/default`. Or if you use persistent shopping cart the do it for `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`.

Find the following section...

```
<?php if ($this->canShip()): ?>
    <li class="control">
        <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
    <li class="control">
        <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...and remove it. Find the following section...

```
<?php if (!$this->canShip()): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="1" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

...and just remove `if` condition

```
<input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="1" />
```

As a result you have combined address step which will be using as billing and shipping.

Comment: Yes , it works . i try shipping and billing address in one page . this help me on it .  Thanks